# No command to wait for AWS RDS Proxy to get created

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I went through [AWS RDS WAIT documentation](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/rds/wait/index.html) but couldn't find any way to wait for RDS Proxy to get created.

Is there any hack or workaround to wait explicitly before going to the next command in sequence?

Comment: You will have to write your own.

Comment: Any pointers to start writing my own wrapper around AWS APIs? All I know is they are async and as soon as I fire a request I get the resource arn and other details as a response. Do you think it's a good idea to perform a reversible action inside RDS proxy and wait for success? @Marcin

Comment: waiter is just a basic loop, which periodicly (e.g. every 10 s) checks a status of a resource. For RDS proxy you would use [describe-db-proxies](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/rds/describe-db-proxies.html) to check `Status`. When `Status` is `available` the loop would finish.

Comment: No problem. I will provide the comment as an answer if you don't mind.

Answer (score 0):

Waiter is just a basic loop, which periodically (e.g. every 10 s) checks a status of a resource. For RDS proxy you would use [describe-db-proxies](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/rds/describe-db-proxies.html) to check Status. When Status is available the loop would finish.